# Kotlin arrow transform a List of failures to a Failure of a list

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

How can I transform the following:

```
List<Try<String>>
```

to:

```
Try<List<String>>
```

Using kotlin and the functional library arrow (0.8.2). I would like to wrap it in a custom exception. It does not matter which one of the 'String' failed.

**Update:**

As the below answers will suffice, but I find it really hard to read. So, I implemented the following:

Create the following function:

```
    fun getFailedStrings(result: List<Try<String>>): List<Failure> {
return result.fold(
    initial = listOf(),
    operation = { accumulator, nextUpdate ->
        nextUpdate.fold(
            ifSuccess = { accumulator },
            ifFailure = { accumulator + Failure(it) }
        )
    })
```

}

Then use the result of the function:

```
  return if (failedStrings.isNotEmpty()) {
      failedStrings.first() // or whatever fits your usecase
  } else {
     // strings is the initial result of List<Try<String>>
      Success(strings.mapNotNull { it.orNull() })
   }
```

Comment: Your `Try<List<String>>` can contain multiple strings but only one exception. You would therefore need to first decide how you would combine exceptions. If multiple of your `Try`s are failures, which exception would you want? The first one? The last one? A new one with a cause set to the first or last one?

Comment: Good question. A new one (custom). It does not matter which one failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we don't care about keeping the original exceptions we could do something like this with traverse:

```
val traversedTries = tries.traverse(Try.applicative(), ::identity)
```

This will return an instance of type `Try<ListK<String>>` with either all the strings or the first exception it finds.

`ListK` extends from `List` but we can optionally cast it by adding `.map { it as List<String> }` in the end if we need it to be `Try<List<String>>`

Alternatively, if we want to split the successes and failures we can create the following function:

```
fun <A> List<Try<A>>.splitSuccessFailure() : Tuple2<List<A>, List<Throwable>> =
  fold(emptyList<A>() toT emptyList<Throwable>()) { (successes, failures), it -> 
    it.fold({ successes toT (failures + it) }, { (successes + it) toT failures })  
  }
```

Then, when we want to use it we can do the following:

```
val (successes, failures) = invalidTries.splitSuccessFailure()
```

Giving us two lists with the success values and failures respectively.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the the '.traverse' extention method for Kotlin list.

Comment: The import you need is:
`import arrow.data.extensions.list.traverse.*` and you also need to add a dependency to `arrow-extras-extensions`

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
 fun convert(input: List<Try<String>>): Try<List<String>> =
    input.fold(Try.just(emptyList())) { acc, i ->
        acc.flatMap { list ->
            i.flatMap {
                Try.just(list + it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be great if the use of arrow library can achieve more readability